# Realm C# - LINQ for empty collections

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I've got realm implemented in a PCL for Xamarin. This works fine, and as it should (data is being stored and retrieved).

Now that I'm building more and more features I'm running into the situation that I can't find a way to query empty collections.

I need to return a `IRealmCollection<Customer>` because of model binding, so I can't enumerate and THEN filter items out that have no blogentries.

Any idea how I can make this happen on an IQueryable?

I tried

```
 var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
 var customers = realm.All<Customer>();
 // errors out - only Realm-managed props can be used
 customers = customers.Where(x => x.BlogEntries.Count > 0));  
 // errors out - Any() is not supported
 customers = customers.Where(x => x.BlogEntries.Any()); 
 // errors out - Datatype mismatch in comparison
 customers = customers.Where(x => x.BlogEntries != null); 
 // errors out - Datatype mismatch in comparison
 customers = customers.Where(x => x.BlogEntries == default(IList<BlogEntries>));
```

Comment: Why even attempt to query an empty collection? If its empty, it will never give a result. Instead, qualify if the collection is empty and ignore it if it is. Think of the collection like a box. Do you try and grab an item from a box, or do you check to see if it has anything in it first?

Comment: @Takarii I only need customers that have blogposts. This is a realm-specific question that requires a different answer than regular .NET questions.

Comment: Have you tried a single line query like `realm.All<Customer>().Where(x => x.BlogEntries.Count > 0).ToList(); `? (i assume the extra closing bracket is a typo)

Comment: @ErikJ. Currently (v1.2 and under) doing that without taking the query `ToList` **and then** filtering is not directly possible. I have altered a few data models to fit this need but they are not ideal but due to the size of the data, taking it to a List was not an option due to memory usage in my case, but if your dataset of `Customer`s is "small" using `ToList` is a quick way to get it done... When Realm does add support for doing this directly, it would be a simple code change.

Comment: The whole point is that I'm hooking it up to an android recycleradapter, meaning that the adapter is directly updated with new info, without having to turn it into an actual "list" that's no longer bound t realm. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not supported as of Realm Xamarin 1.2.0. What you could do is implement a poor-man's collection notifications to work around the issue:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private IRealmCollection<BlogEntry> _blogEntries;
    private IEnumerable<Customer> _customers;

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set { Set(ref _customers, value); }
    }

    public MyViewModel
    {
        Customers = realm.All<Customer>()
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(c => !c.BlogEntries.Any())
                         .ToArray();

        _blogEntries = realm.All<BlogEntry>().AsRealmCollection();
        _blogEntries.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            var updatedCustomers = realm.All<Customer>()
                                        .AsEnumerable()
                                        .Where(c => !c.BlogEntries.Any())
                                        .ToArray();

            if (!IsEquivalent(updatedCustomers, Customers))
            {
                Customers = updatedCustomers;
            }
        };
    }

    private bool IsEquivalent(Customer[] a, Customer[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!a[i].Equals(b[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

As when we call `ToArray()` we only lose collection change notifications, we implement them naively by observing the blog entries collection in Realm and doing a simplistic check if anything has been updated. If you feel like it, you could extend this solution and wrap it in a custom implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` and bind to that. Then, you could even apply some semantics to raise the correct collection change events (or opt for a simple .Reset for each change).

To address any performance concerns, calling `ToArray` on a Realm collection will not materialize objects' properties, so it's relatively cheap. The only somewhat expensive operation is iterating over all `Customer` objects and checking their `BlogEntries` lists. My advise would be to give it a try and see if it performs satisfactory for your use case.